# MQMapView setRegion: causes app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, exception, mapquest

I'm trying to center my mapView on the user's location, but an exception is thrown that's caught by the `AppDelegate` before the mapView or view controller are even loaded.

`mapView` is an `MQMapView`
userLocation is assigned earlier from `mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate`

```
MQCoordinateSpan userSpan = MQCoordinateSpanMake(1000, 1000);

MQCoordinateRegion userRegion = MQCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation, userSpan);

[mapView setRegion:userRegion animated:true];
```

As far as I can make out from the MapQuest developer guide I'm calling setRegion correctly. Any idea what might be causing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having crashes with my iPhone4S and console revealed nan values for region.  After trying about 7 different solutions from SO and various suggestions from Apple DTS, I solved it by eliminating the regionThatFits call.  I simply used:

```
CLLocationDistance visibleDistance = 100000; // 100 kilometers
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, visibleDistance, visibleDistance);

[_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

Apparently there is a problem with that regionThatFits method.